# Add new field to existing index or join in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 12M records inserted into elastic search index.

Assume below is my json :

```
[
  {
    "c1": 1,
    "c2": "a",
    "c3": "x"
  },
  {
    "c1": 2,
    "c2": "b",
    "c3": "y"
  },
  {
    "c1": 3,
    "c2": "c",
    "c3": "z"
  }
]
```

And to these fields I want to add new field to existing index with or without c1 reference

```
[
    {
        "c1":1,
        "c4":"aa"
    },
    {
        "c1":1,
        "c4":"bb"
    },
    {
        "c1":1,
        "c4":"cc"
    }
]
```

and my index should be like :

```
[
  {
    "c1": 1,
    "c2": "a",
    "c3": "x",
    "c4": "aa"
  },
  {
    "c1": 2,
    "c2": "b",
    "c3": "y",
    "c4": "bb"
  },
  {
    "c1": 3,
    "c2": "c",
    "c3": "z",
    "c4": "cc"
  }
]
```

I have google and search for alternate help, but what I found is parent-child relation within index.

how to join or add or merge column to existing index?
If yes how to bulk insert it?

Comment: Dont speak about column in elasticsearch data. We use documents with fields. Please give us better example (not with a sql like data but with jsons and what field you want to add).

Comment: Need some sample data